# Want to know if there is any way to Print from UWP App without showing PrintDialog.

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml, posprinter

Need suggestions on printing from UWP App without showing PrintDialog. Tried implementing using POS Printer API But unable to connect to HP Printer which is connected to NETWORK.

Want to remove dependency with Brokered Component which am using for Printing.

Comment: Your device doesn't support POS printer, and you also don't want use Brokered Component, I don't think you have any  other choices. Maybe vote up [this](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/6185763-allow-direct-printing-without-modern-ui-print-dial).